# Why does the new light-client example throw a warning?

Tags: security, eth-lightwallet

Even though I use the new example, lightwallet throws me:

> The `new KeyStore` constructor has been deprecated in favor of `KeyStore.createVault()`, and will be removed in a future version. Read [issue #109](https://github.com/ConsenSys/eth-lightwallet/issues/109) for info.

This is the recommended sample instead of:

> Sample old-style usage with hooked web3 provider (still works, but less secure because uses fixed salts).

https://github.com/ConsenSys/eth-lightwallet

Should I be worried?

```
var lightwallet = require('eth-lightwallet');
// the seed is stored encrypted by a user-defined password
var password = 'Enter password for encryption';

lightwallet.keystore.createVault({
  password: password,
  // seedPhrase: seedPhrase, // Optionally provide a 12-word seed phrase
  // salt: fixture.salt,     // Optionally provide a salt.
                             // A unique salt will be generated otherwise.
  // hdPathString: hdPath    // Optional custom HD Path String
}, function (err, ks) {

  // Some methods will require providing the `pwDerivedKey`,
  // Allowing you to only decrypt private keys on an as-needed basis.
  // You can generate that value with this convenient method:
  ks.keyFromPassword(password, function (err, pwDerivedKey) {
    if (err) throw err;

    // generate five new address/private key pairs
    // the corresponding private keys are also encrypted
    ks.generateNewAddress(pwDerivedKey, 5);
    var addr = ks.getAddresses();

    ks.passwordProvider = function (callback) {
      var pw = prompt("Please enter password", "Password");
      callback(null, pw);
    };

    // Now set ks as transaction_signer in the hooked web3 provider
    // and you can start using web3 using the keys/addresses in ks!
  });
});
```